# How to auto switch between Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to make a slider with auto sliding. Ie. move to the next picture. It's a slightly special slider. I have radio buttons that control the which image it is on.

How can I make it auto slide?

```
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-1">A</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-2">B</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-3">C</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-4">D</a>
```

Comment: instead of using useless ID's in your specific case you can go by removig all that ID's and using the element's `.index( this )` in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)  for auto switch between radio button in every second.

Check out this fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(test, 1000);
  var i = 1;

  function test() {
    i = (i % 4) + 1;
    $('#st-control-' + i).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1" />
<a href="#st-panel-1">A</a>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2" />
<a href="#st-panel-2">B</a>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3" />
<a href="#st-panel-3">C</a>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4" />
<a href="#st-panel-4">D</a>
```

Comment: Hi, that looks good, thanks! Is there a way to reset it such that if I pick one it goes from that one instead of jumping to the where the loop is?